# Unexpected SQL division results?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, division

I use SQL Server.

Working with divisions I collected my findings in these two queries that you can reproduce with your SQL Server version.

I was expecting from Division with Integer to have the same value in both cases.
Because regardless the values in my table, if I get unexpected results I end up with a logical bug, sometimes difficult to investigate.

**SQL A:**

```
WITH s AS (
    SELECT 'Integer' AS c, 1 AS k UNION
    SELECT 'Float', 1 UNION
    SELECT 'NULL', NULL
) 
SELECT 
    c AS [Type],
    k/10 AS                          'Division',
    CAST(k as numeric(38,4))/10 AS 'Cast',
    COALESCE(k, 0)/10           AS 'Coalesce',
    COALESCE(k, .0)/10          AS 'Coalesce with float'
FROM s;
```

**Result A**

```
Type        Division    Cast        Coalesce    Coalesce with float
Float       0           0.100000    0           0.100000
Integer     0           0.100000    0           0.100000
NULL        NULL        NULL        0           0.000000
```

**SQL B:**

```
WITH s AS (
    SELECT 'Integer' AS c, 1 AS k UNION
    SELECT 'Float', .1 UNION
    SELECT 'NULL', NULL
) 
SELECT 
    c AS [Type],
    k/10 AS                          'Division',
    CAST(k as numeric(38,4))/10 AS 'Cast',
    COALESCE(k, 0)/10           AS 'Coalesce',
    COALESCE(k, .0)/10          AS 'Coalesce with float'
FROM s;
```

**Result A**

```
Type        Division    Cast        Coalesce    Coalesce with float
Float       0.010000    0.010000    0.010000    0.010000
Integer     0.100000    0.100000    0.100000    0.100000
NULL        NULL        NULL        0.000000    0.000000
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first table is all integers.

`SELECT 'Float', 1 is an INT` is not a float just because you put the word in there. It will be implied as an INT because there is no decimal place.

And then, you know integer division uses integers... for example...

`select 3/10` is 0 instead of .3000 which you would get with `select 3/10.0`. If you want decimal / float to be returned, either the numerator or denominator needs to be a float (or both)

**EDIT**

After your last comment, I understand your question more. When you union different datatypes together, which you did in the second `CTE`, SQL Server is going to implicitly convert them to the necessary data type to accompany all inputs. [See the order of precedence here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql)

So, if you just select * from that cte... you will see your 1 was converted to 1.0. A column can only have a single datatype. In this example, SQL Server would have to choose `INT` or `FLOAT`. If INT was chosen, you'd have data integrity issues.

```
WITH s AS (
    SELECT 'Integer' AS c, 1 AS k UNION
    SELECT 'Float', .1 UNION
    SELECT 'NULL', NULL
) 

select * from s
```

Comment: Please inspect the second statement SELECT 'Float', .1

Comment: @profimedica in that second statement, you have a decimal point. It's the same as 0.1. This is missing in the first, which is why your integer division returns an integer.

Comment: I have to emphases that I create the two scenarios being aware of the effect of adding the dot to create a float. Also I am expecting that the result of integers division to result in an integer and the result of float to result in a float. This is the case of first line in both examples. The unexpected result is on the Integer line, where the participants are the same but the type of output is dictated by the float result.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the same result for these two datasets, use FLOOR() function

**SQL A**

```
WITH s AS (
    SELECT 'Integer' AS c, 1 AS k UNION
    SELECT 'Float', 1 UNION
    SELECT 'NULL', NULL
) 
SELECT c AS [Type],
       FLOOR(k/10) AS 'Division',
       CAST(k as numeric(38,4))/10 AS 'Cast',
       FLOOR(COALESCE(k, 0)/10) AS 'Coalesce',
       COALESCE(k, .0)/10 AS 'Coalesce with float'
FROM s;
```

**SQL B**

```
WITH s AS (
    SELECT 'Integer' AS c, 1 AS k UNION
    SELECT 'Float', .1 UNION
    SELECT 'NULL', NULL
) 
SELECT 
    c AS [Type],
    FLOOR(k/10) AS 'Division',
    CAST(k as numeric(38,4))/10 AS 'Cast',
    FLOOR(COALESCE(k, 0)/10) AS 'Coalesce',
    COALESCE(FLOOR(k), .0)/10 AS 'Coalesce with float'
FROM s;
```

Result on both queries

```
Type    Division    Cast        Coalesce    Coalesce with float
Float   0           0.100000    0           0.100000
Integer 0           0.100000    0           0.100000
NULL    NULL        NULL        0           0.000000
```

Comment: In your SQL B floor results in an integer that is transformed back to float by oalesce: COALESCE(FLOOR(k), .0). Indeed, your approach will force the type of result, scsimon explained the type precedence tah is decided for entire column.